# Error on sql request on access vba

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I've an error on this code:

```
 Promo_var = Modifiable84.Value
   MsgBox Promo_var

   DoCmd.Hourglass True 'icone tablier a true

   ' set to break on all errors
   Application.SetOption "Error Trapping", 0

   ' start with a clean file built from the template file
   sTemplate = CurrentProject.Path & "\PlanificationAnnuelle_Template.xlsx"
   sOutput = CurrentProject.Path & "\PlanificationAnnuelle.xlsx"
   If Dir(sOutput) <> "" Then Kill sOutput
   FileCopy sTemplate, sOutput

   ' Create the Excel Applicaiton, Workbook and Worksheet and Database object
   Set appExcel = New Excel.Application
   Set wbk = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(sOutput)
   Set wks = appExcel.Worksheets(cTabTwo)

   sSQL = "SELECT Nom, PROMO, Semestre1A, Semestre1B, Semestre2A, Semestre2B, CatSemestre1A, CatSemestre1B, CatSemestre2A, CatSemestre2B FROM Planif WHERE CatSemestre1A > 0 OR CatSemestre1B > 0 OR CatSemestre2A > 0 OR CatSemestre2B > 0 WHERE PROMO = '" & Promo_var & "' ORDER BY Nom ASC "
   MsgBox sSQL
   Set dbs = CurrentDb
   Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset(sSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)
```

The error occurs on these line:

```
Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset(sSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)
```

The error is error

> '3075' Syntax error (missing operator)

I can't find where is the problem.
i've tried several sql change but i'm loose

Comment: So bad i've two WHERE ! i'm so break!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You call `WHERE` two times in your query

```
SELECT Nom, PROMO, Semestre1A, Semestre1B, Semestre2A, Semestre2B, CatSemestre1A, CatSemestre1B, CatSemestre2A, CatSemestre2B 
FROM Planif 
WHERE CatSemestre1A > 0 OR CatSemestre1B > 0 OR CatSemestre2A > 0 OR CatSemestre2B > 0 
WHERE PROMO = '" & Promo_var & "' 
ORDER BY Nom ASC
```